# How to deal with players that spam pings?

Tags: league-of-legends

**You can mute players, but you will still hear and see their ping spams.**

How should you deal with players that spam pings, besides telling them to stop?

If you mute the sound for pings, you might not hear/see the useful pings another teamate does.

Is it ok to report them after the game?

**EDIT:**

I'm talking about "ping-flamers": They ping too often. Mostly the same thing 5 times in 2 seconds.

Comment: step up to silver league xD - I would say it's fine to report them. Since the behaviour is ______.

Comment: What about the ones who ping in the wrong situation and way too often?

Comment: @Shelby115 dont listen to them ;) easier for you than for the rest of the team.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Do you have the will to accept any of the answers? :) just wondering

Comment: @Lokuzt you must be new here because you beg for reputation. the only thing i find useful in your answer is the very first sentence.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Im not begging for rep but I like to see if my answer was useful. And I honestly think that you won't get any better answer than the answers I and ronnie provided. Even Shelby115 stated that.

Comment: 5 pings for the same thing is not that rare of a practice because a lot of people dont see a single ping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ping spams can be annoying but they might identify a situation that may require desperate attention.

It can be just a flamer pinging non-stop.
The ping-mute would not be a pleasant solution. LoL has a variety of pings that are really helpful for a team to communicate without chat. Who to Target, sinalize missing champion, asking for help, etc..

You can report if you please but people at the tribunal have no proof they were pinging like hell.

> Your best bet is to politely ask them to ping less and to ping more
>   effectively. Because pings are extremely useful.

**REGARDING THE EDIT**

Ping flamers are not that common (At least I don't get them, maybe once a month in EUW). If asking them to stop and ping less doesn't work try lowering the game sound. Not completely removing the sound but lowering it.

If you are confortable with no-sound go for it but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: +1 good answer, but edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW did you edit? I'm not seeing any edit

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't rule out ping mute. I was playing with no sound the other day and still caught 90% of the pings my team used. As long as you pay attention to the minimap you should be fine. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Shelby115 for people with good map awareness you can catch pings but imagina you're in a trade intensive lane. You want see the pings on the river for example. Situations like these are really good for pings with sound.

Comment: @Shelby115 but ping spams "blur" your map vision, because count wont be able to see whats going on on the minimap if there are too many pings.

Comment: @Lokuzt True, I was (for some reason) thinking only about after lane-phase is over. Not sure why though.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW added an edit to my answer.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW That shouldn't be too big of an issue. You shouldn't really be relying on the minimap to tell you everything, just what you need (i.e. Who is where, or even that an -enemy- is somewhere not even necessarily which enemy).

Comment: "Ping flamers are not that common." Have you played normals in NA? I disagree entirely with this. I get them at least once a day. And that's "too common" imo.

Comment: @Shelby115 I don't get them in EUW maybe it's a region thing. I will edit though.

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW did my answer help in any way?

Comment: @Lokuzt nothing really new to me, to be honest. the first sentence is very good!

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW I think there's nothing more I can say. It's one of those situations that if you have a ping spammer you'll have to deal with it and play through it. If you feel like accepting my answer you're at will :D

Comment: @Lokuzt Honestly, this is probably the best answer that can be given. I feel this is one of those questions that verifies what people already know. Which is still useful because people are hoping for alternatives that don't exist, at least objectively. I guess you could mention the "asking nicely" answer haha.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a new volume adjustment slide for pings since the new patch. so if someone keeps pinging to much you can just turn the sound off at the sound options.

Comment: why turns of the sound for usefull pings too and isnt a solution for the minimap distortion. but good answer hoewever.

Comment: It kinda is the only thing to do as they are meant to be annoying so people would notice them. so there are 3 things you can do.
1. Either ask them to stop
2. Mute the pings if they don't
3. Ignore it all together.
And the "can you report them" question well, there is a option to report people that are spamming. So if they are really spamming with the pings for no reason at all you can report them yes. (this also includes chat/emote spam.)